# Items not getting added in Arraylist

Tags: java, android, api, android-intent, arraylist

This is how i am trying to add "ids" from api to my arraylist

```
int id;


 private List<HashMap<String, Object>> 
               getMovies(JSONArray jMovies) throws NullPointerException {


 int movieCount = jMovies.length();


 List<HashMap<String, Object>> movieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


 HashMap<String, Object> movie = null;

    //Taking each movie, parses and adds to list object
    for (int i = 0; i < movieCount; i++) {

        try {
            JSONObject getid=(JSONObject) jMovies.get(i);

            movie = getMovie(getid);
            movieList.add(movie);
            id =Integer.parseInt(getid.getString("id"));


        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        getNumberlist(i,id);
    }

    return movieList;
}


public ArrayList<Integer> ids=new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void getNumberlist(int i,int id)
{
    ids.add(i,id);

}

public List<Integer> getNumberslist()
{ return this.ids;
}
```

and trying to get it on Itemclick listener as

```
MovieJSONParser mj = new MovieJSONParser();


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {


   Intent intent = new Intent(this,next.class);

   if(position==0) {
       int id1 = mj.getNumberslist().get(0);
       intent.putExtra("id",id1);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
    if(position==1) {
        int id1 = mj.getNumberslist().get(1);
        intent.putExtra("id",id1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(position==2) {
        int id1 = mj.getNumberslist().get(2);
        intent.putExtra("id",id1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(position==3) {
        int id1 = mj.getNumberslist().get(3);
        intent.putExtra("id",id1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
```

Comment: never silently swallow exceptions `catch (JSONException e) {

        }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i am getting the error: Exception : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Help me solve it pls

Comment: I think that the problem is that you ignore the exception.`catch (JSONException e) {

        }`

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are catching Exception, at least print stack trace so that it will be easier to debug code.

While getting JSONObject using jMovies.get(i) , your api data is empty so you will get index out of bound exception.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < movieCount; i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject getid=(JSONObject) jMovies.get(i);

                movie = getMovie(getid);
                movieList.add(movie);
                id =Integer.parseInt(getid.getString("id"));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getNumberlist(i,id);
        }
```

Check if you are getting data in jMovies.

Comment: Yes i am getting the data in jMovies as when it is passed in getMovie(getid) 

The objects in that List are updated with the data and returned.

Comment: You will get data if jMovies is not empty. But as you have added comment that you are getting Exception : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0, this will only happen if jMovies is empty and you try to get data at 0th index using jMovies.get(i). Try logging value of jMovies.get(i), also try logging value of jMovies.length.